# http.createServer([requestListener]) with additional Parameter

Tags: node.js, http

[http-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-auth) says to call `http.createServer` with two parameters:

```
// Creating new HTTP server. 
http.createServer(basic, function(req, res) {
    res.end("Welcome to private area - " + req.user + "!");
})
```

But the [node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener) say:

> http.createServer([requestListener])
>
> Returns a new instance of http.Server.
>
> The requestListener is a function which is automatically added to the
>   'request' event.

What is `http.createServer` doing with the first (in this case `basic`) parameter?

Comment: That is true, module breaks a rule (YOU NEVER CHANGE WHAT YOU DON'T OWN) to provide flexible way for integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http-auth` adds authentication method to vanilla `Node.js` `http`.  See more here: https://github.com/gevorg/http-auth/blob/master/src/server/http.coffee

This method checks arguments and based on their number adds proper authentication logic.